# Почему в Enumerable.Any() отдается приоритет свойству Count выше чем MoveNext()?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Почему в теле метода [`Enumerable.Any<TSource>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs,8788153112b7ffd0,references) сначала пытаются достать свойство `Count` (внутри метода [`TryGetNonEnumeratedCount`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,1b0addd9ae1db08d)) и если не получается, то возвращается `MoveNext()` который как раз возвращает нужное нам bool значение. Почему бы сразу не сделать условный `return MoveNext()`? Какие преимущества у такого подхода? В IL никакой разницы между вызовом `get` у свойства и вызова метода нет, оба дёргаются за счет `callvirt`

Comment: все зависит от того, к какой коллекции это все применяется

Comment: @Grundy можно пример?

Comment: оптимизация потому что, первичная инициализация энемератора требует создания его экземпляра, а выдача Count не требует инициализации энумератора.

Comment: @aepot справедливо в принципе, даже не подумал над этим

Comment: Я кажется даже как-то задавал тут вопрос насчёт того, не оптимальнее ли использовать `Count`, чем `Any` (для коллекции, где он точно есть), а выходит разницы то и нет в итоге )

Comment: @CrazyElf по сложности алгоритма нет разницы, а вот по объему кода есть. Так что если это изначально массив или список, то лучше родные свойства использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оптимизация потому что.

Первичная инициализация энумератора требует создания его экземпляра, а выдача `Count` не требует инициализации энумератора.

Код ([GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L10-L21)):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(source, out int count) ? count != 0 : WithEnumerator(source);

    static bool WithEnumerator(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        using IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator(); // вот оно, создание экземпляра энумератора
        return e.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

```
public static bool TryGetNonEnumeratedCount<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, out int count)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.source);
    }

    if (source is ICollection<TSource> collectionoft)
    {
        count = collectionoft.Count;
        return true;
    }

    if (source is IIListProvider<TSource> listProv)
    {
        int c = listProv.GetCount(onlyIfCheap: true);
        if (c >= 0)
        {
            count = c;
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (source is ICollection collection)
    {
        count = collection.Count;
        return true;
    }

    count = 0;
    return false;
}
```